RX5600XT black screen Ununtu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu and Kubuntu 24.04 on i5 12400 + RX5600XT and give black screen after installation, who was able to fix it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
